# How to read line of code that includes numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Sorry for the weird question, but I am reviewing the code and can not understand the meaning of the line of code.

I have a NumPy array with `(23345,23345,4)` dimensions and let's call it `X`.

What does this line mean:

```
I2[I2>10000] = 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

This means replace elements in the array that are larger than 10k by just 10k.